# Como mandar parametros de angular hacia un WS creado php

Tags: php, angular

Lo que quiero es mandar parametros de mi peticion  http de angular 7 hacia mi WebService creado en php pero me sale el error `Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen impide leer el recurso remoto`

Código WS:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type:application/json"); 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');



$Func = $_GET['Function'];


switch ($Func) {
    case 'Detail':

$json = file_get_contents('http://localhost/store/public/UserStore');
echo $json;
        break;
    case 'Insert':
echo 'Insert';
  break;
    default:
        echo 'Nada';
        break;
}

?>
```

Código Angular:

```
    InsertArticulos(fruta:fruta) {
        console.log(fruta);
    return this.http.post(this.url+"?Function=Insert",fruta);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

mm parece un problema de CORS revisa este codigo

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");  
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');  
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');   
}  

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {  

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))  
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");  

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))  
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");  
}
```